# Nav Button combined with "Go" button?

Tags: search, drop-down-menu, navigation, nav

I'm creating a directory type of site with posts in many different categories. Instead of a navbar, I want to use one nav button at the top of the site that looks like a Search box, with a "Go" button.

I just think this idea fits the theme.

Anyway, the box will have a dropdown, to select a category. It won't actually search, it will just take you to the posts in the selected category. (Ex. If you click "Websites" in the dropdown box, it will take you to the "Website" category page in the blog.)

However, I want it to work only when you hit the "Go" button--like a search box--not just when you select the category--like a normal nav dropdown.

Is this possible? What's the easy or best way?

Comment: Hi SCYankee. So basicly you need a select-box and a button (kind of submit) with label "Go". Right?

Comment: Yes. Select box in the sense of a dropdown where user can click on a selection in the list.